# How to edit inset face after executing inset command

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have a mesh with an inset face which looks like this:

[image]

The reason I have inset the face is to make a nice edge when adding a subdivision modifier. But if the edge ends up too sharp for my taste, what do I do? I can no longer move the inset face the way it did when executing the inset command... is there a way to easily edit this?

Answer (score 1):

- Select the vertices which compose edges and scale.  <kbd>S</kbd>
- You probably know you can scale in two dimensions.  Lets assume XZ in
  your model.
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
- You probably know you can choose the center point of the scale if
  necessary.  Moving the cursor to the bottom middle might be your style. Otherwise you might move the points in z direction.
- Otherwise undo or delete your work and inset a second time

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the answer to this but for a more complicated scenario where the inset is not along an exact plane so you can't just scale it along an axis and I ended up finding another way.

You can use the *Edge Slide* command.

You have to be in edge select mode, select just the edges (not the entire face like you'd do for an inset), then use the Slide Edge command, not sure what the default shortcut is but it's under *Mesh > Edges > Edge Slide* or *Tool Shelf > Tools > Mesh Deform > Edge Slide*.

It's not 100% the same, but it's pretty close. In your case for example it would be more accurate making the inset bigger instead of smaller (the circle will start to curve/deform), so it would be better to scale it like the other answer suggested, but for when that's not an option this works pretty well.